# php grep <div class="container" src=https://..>

Tags: php, html, regex

I want to grep the pattern inside div class="container".  here is my
code

```
<?php
$text = ' <div class="container" src="https://cdn.ibctamil.com/ibctamil/ibc_tamil_tv/playlist.m3u8?zecaststarttime=1506455875&zecastendtime=1506479275&zecasthash=z8GSRoz4YawDqICWGTnepikvYKOgUtkMe-JdSOrwaWc=" data-mediatype="video" data-autoplay="0" data-showartwork="0" data-theme="light" data-od="0"></div>';

$text = preg_replace('/^(.*)(<div class="container:"> src = "".*)(<\/div>)$/', '$2', $text);


echo $text;
?>
```

// on output i want the url start with https://cdn.ibctamil.com/ibctamil/ibc_tamil_tv/playlist.m3u8?zecaststarttime=1506455875&zecastendtime=1506479275&zecasthash=z8GSRoz4YawDqICWGTnepikvYKOgUtkMe-JdSOrwaWc=

Answer (score 0):

You aren't `grep`ing anything here, you are using a regex to process HTML which you shouldn't do. Your regex also has multiple typos which is why it doesn't work.

Here's how you should handle this:

```
$html = '<div class="container" src="https://cdn.ibctamil.com/ibctamil/ibc_tamil_tv/playlist.m3u8?zecaststarttime=1506455875&zecastendtime=1506479275&zecasthash=z8GSRoz4YawDqICWGTnepikvYKOgUtkMe-JdSOrwaWc=" data-mediatype="video" data-autoplay="0" data-showartwork="0" data-theme="light" data-od="0"></div>';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$divs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div');
foreach ($divs as $div) {
    if($div->getAttribute('class') == 'container') {
        echo $div->getAttribute('src');
    }
}
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/IniNf

A regex approach which will fail if any of the data changes would be:

```
^(.*)<div class="container" src="(.*?)".*<\/div>
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/5GBHbc/1/

Issues with your regex:

1. `container:` doesnt exist
2. `:">` is also not present
3. `src =` is also not present
4. Your capture group is too large
5. Your looking for an empty `src` attribute with `""`, the `.*` needs to be inside that. `[^"]+"` would work better because that takes everything until the next double quote

Answer (score 0):

```
  <?php

$text = "<div class='container' src='https://cdn.ibctamil.com/ibctamil/ibc_tamil_tv/playlist.m3u8?zecaststarttime=1506455875&zecastendtime=1506479275&zecasthash=z8GSRoz4YawDqICWGTnepikvYKOgUtkMe-JdSOrwaWc=' data-mediatype='video' data-autoplay='0' data-showartwork='0' data-theme='light' data-od='0'></div>";


preg_match_all("@src='([^']+)'@",$text, $result);


$result[0][0] = substr($result[0][0], 4);


$NewResult=implode(' ',$result[0]);
$NewResult=trim($NewResult,"''");
echo($NewResult);
```

and the output is only the src :

```
https://cdn.ibctamil.com/ibctamil/ibc_tamil_tv/playlist.m3u8?zecaststarttime=1506455875&zecastendtime=1506479275&zecasthash=z8GSRoz4YawDqICWGTnepikvYKOgUtkMe-JdSOrwaWc=
```